# AngularJS.. Possibility of IF-Statement in .then function()?

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJS.
I am trying to use IF-Statement inside of a function in Controller.js but I don't know how to approach there.

[The Code trying to implement IF-Statement]

```
ProjectService.getProject($stateParams.project_id)
    .then(function(project) {
        // if $stateParams.project_id exists, then execute ABC
        // ABC..
        // if no existence, then exit.
});
```

I tried to search similar ones as mine, but I couldn't make it.
Perhaps, if may not work in a function in AngularJS?

Can someone please kindly help me?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Do you want to check if a variable exists or some resource (URL)? Why not simply put `if($stateParams.project_id)` around your `ProjectService.getProject(...)` call?

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! I will try to remember this kind of method. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do it like this:

```
ProjectService.getProject()
    .then(function(project) {
        if($stateParams.project_id){
           // ABC..
        }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It sure did work! I will try to remember this method and use it next time. :)